# segmentation faults in MPI-2

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi

any idea why the following would give me a segfault?

```
buf_int = new int[12];
buf_int[0] = stx1.min;
buf_int[1] = stx1.max;
buf_int[2] = stx2.min;
buf_int[3] = stx2.max;
buf_int[4] = sty1.min;
buf_int[6] = sty2.max;

MPI_Bcast(&buf_int, 12, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

stx1.min = buf_int[0];
```

if i comment out the final line, i do not get a segfault, but if i leave it in, i get the

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
```

error which turns out is a segmentation fault. if the error cannot be deduced from the code given, i can include more.

buf_int is declared as

```
int* buf_int;
```

Comment: Post the signature of `MPI_Bcast` and the type of `buf_int`.

Comment: what do you mean the signature of MPI_Bcast? like the return code?

Comment: I meant how the `MPI_Bcast` has been declared; what are the parameter types?

Comment: the arguments for MPI_Bcast can be viewed at http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Bcast.html. the arguments MPI_INT and MPI_COMM_WORLD are predefined types in the mpi header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the signature of `MPI_Bcast` is this:

```
int MPI_Bcast(
  void *buffer,
  int count,
  MPI_Datatype datatype,
  int root,
  MPI_Comm comm
);
```

as taken from it's [documentation](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Bcast.html), you should call the function as:

```
MPI_Bcast(buf_int, 12, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

That is, pass `buf_int` as first argument, instead of `&bug_int`.

You can see the example-code by scrolling down the [page](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Bcast.html), and compare the usage.

Comment: you're exactly correct! in class we had been calling &buf_int ... we must have been declaring the array in a different manner i suppose. thanks!